# To prove that the division of two entire functions is rational

Tags: complex-analysis

If f and g are entire functions such that $|f(z)|\lt|g(z)|$ for $|z|\gt1$, then show that $f(z)/g(z)$ is a rational function.

I am thinking that if I can just prove that $f/g$ is a meromorphic function on the extended plane. And then maybe show that $g(z)$ can't be zero at some point in $|z|\gt1$ so that $f/g$ is rational? But I am stuck at here. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like GAGA theorem.

Comment: @JackyChong What's that?

Comment: Since $|g(z)| > |f(z)| \ge 0$ you see that $g$ has no zeros in $|z|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's relax the inequality to $|f|\le |g|$ on the open set $U=\{z:|z|>1\}.$ (This allows $f=g=0$ everywhere. Is $0/0$ rational? Probably not. Let's forget about that case and assume $g$ is nonconstant.)

Since $g$ is nonconstant, it only has isolated zeros in $U.$ Let $a$ be one of them. Then $f/g$ is bounded in a deleted neighborhood of $a,$ hence has a removable singularity there. We can thus regard $f/g$ as holomorphic in $U.$ Note that $|f/g|\le 1$ in $U.$

Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be the zeros of $g,$ counted by multiplicity, in $\{|z|\le 1\}.$ Then

$$\tag 1 h(z)=\frac{f(z)(z-a_1)\cdots (z-a_n)}{g(z)}$$

extends to be entire. For $z\in U$ we have

$$|h(z)| \le |z-a_1|\cdots |z-a_n|.$$

Thus $h$ grows "like a polynomial". An entire function that grows like a polynomial is a polynomial. Thus we have

$$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{h(z)}{(z-a_1)\cdots (z-a_n)}.$$

Therefore $f/g$ is rational.

Comment: So I get the basic idea, we can prove that $p(z)f(z)/g(z)$ is rational and because $p(z)$ is a polynomial, so that $f(z)/g(z)$ is rational? But how to prove that $p(z)f(z)/g(z)$ is rational?

Comment: And when z is equal to $z_1, ... or z_n$, the whole thing is going to be zero. How does that help?

Comment: Well $pf/g$ is entire, and you need to spend more time than a few minutes thinking about this.

Comment: It is entire and bounded by $|p(z)|$ for large $z$. That restricts the set of functions.

Comment: But how to connect this fact with rationality?

Comment: Have you seen the result that an entire function that "grows like a polynomial" is a polynomial?

Comment: Nope? Can I use that directly?

Comment: The result is: If $f$ is entire and $|f(z)| \le A + B|z|^k,$ then $f$ is a polynomial of degree no more than $k.$

Comment: Okay, so we can use the fact above to prove that f is a polynomial. And because g cannot be zero, so it is also a polynomial. As a result, $f/g$ is rational?

Comment: @TrashFailure I changed my hint to a more complete answer, allowing for $\le$ in the given inequality.

Comment: Thanks. From above, I see the argument if $h(z)$ is entire, but how do we deal with the case for zeros of $g$ outside the disk?

Comment: @TrashFailure You don't need to worry about them. The zeros of $f$ kill them off. Remember, $f/g$ is holomorphic in $U.$

Comment: Could you elaborate more about how does zeros of $f$ would kill them off? Edit: NVM